# SQL Database going into recovery pending after machine restart

Tags: sql-server

> 2023-08-07 20:08:46.44 spid32s     Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
>
> 2023-08-07 20:08:46.44 spid32s     Unable to open the physical file "X:\SQL Data\XXX.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)".
>
> 2023-08-07 20:08:46.44 spid31s     Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
>
> 2023-08-07 20:08:46.44 spid31s     Unable to open the physical file "X:\SQL Data\XXX.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)".
>
> 2023-08-07 20:08:46.44 spid32s     Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>
> 2023-08-07 20:08:46.44 spid32s     FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'L:\SQL Logs\XXX.LDF'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.

Gave everyone full control of the drives/child folders to rule out a permission error.
Added MSSQLSERVICE with full control to drives/child folders.

Comment: Is `X:` a network drive? Could be it's not connecting before SQL Server starts up. Set the service to Automatic Delayed Start. "Gave everyone full control" bad idea. Everyone means even unauthenticated users, and even other users shouldn't have access to the database files, only the SQL Server service account

Comment: You should make this an answer, it's almost certainly the correct one.

Comment: @JonathanFite Could also be a delayed starting block storage device or virtual disk. Or could be something else entirely, we don't know until OP comes back with more info.

Comment: Just an FYI, networked drive mounting is local to the profile and session.